# Hidden Recaptcha V3 badge is appearing again after some idle time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

I have added the Google Recaptcha V3 through script and applying styles to hide the badge for all other pages where I don't need to see the badge. It's working fine but if the app is idle for some time, the `visibility` style is getting removed.

Below is the code I have used to show or hide the badge.

```
const toggleCaptchaBadge = (show: boolean) => {
  const badge = document.getElementsByClassName('grecaptcha-badge')[0];
  if (badge && badge instanceof HTMLElement) {
    badge.style.visibility = show ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
  }
};
```

Enabling the code in components like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
  toggleCaptchaBadge(true);
  return () => toggleCaptchaBadge(false);
}, []);
```

The badge is re-appearing only if the app is idle. Attached is the screenshot with some time difference and the time also not at all constant. Sometimes the badge is appeared within 1 hour and sometimes it takes 3 or 4 hours.

Below image is shows the badge after 1 hour of idle time.

[image]

Any reason for this and how can this be resolved?

Comment: Having the same issue and can't seem to find documentation on why the badge would render again. Any luck getting to the bottom of this OP?